# Is there way to create Azure Password Protection using Powershell/Graph API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-powershell, azure-ad-graph-api

I am looking for a option or lead to create Password Protection policy in Azure AD either using Powershell or Graph?

Can anyone help me on this.

Thank in advance.

Regards,
Arun

Answer (score 0):

Kindly go through the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-password-ban-bad-on-premises-deploy) to enable azure password protection policy through PowerShell.

Go through this [document](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/itops-talk-blog/step-by-step-implementing-azure-ad-password-protection-on/ba-p/563342) for detailed step by step instructions and scenarios

Comment: Thanks for your response. The link which you shared mainly talk on the on-premises Azure AD password protection.Solution i am looking is for powershell command to create Password protection which is configured from Azure portal "Password Protection" blade.